# Positioning a node in the middle of a multi point path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

To learn Tikz I wanted to recreate the well known reinforcement learning agent ->  environment -> agent plot.

This is what I currently got:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, arrows, shapes, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, math, positioning, calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{rect/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw
    }}
    \tikzset{single/.style={
        ->,
        draw
    }}    
    \tikzset{double/.style={to path={%
        ($(\tikztostart)+(1pt,0)$) |- ($(\tikztotarget)+(0,-1pt)$)
        ($(\tikztostart)+(-1pt,0)$) |- ($(\tikztotarget)+(0,1pt)$)
    },
    ->,
    draw
    }}
    
    
    % Nodes
    \node[style=rect] (agent) at (0,0)   {Agent};
    \node[below=of agent, style=rect] (environment) {Environment};
    
    \path[style=single] (agent.east)  -| ++(1,0) node[style=rectangle] at ($(agent)!0.5!(environment)$) {$A_t$}  |-  (environment.east);
    
    \draw (environment.west) to[double] (agent.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Two questions:

1. How can I position the $A_t$ node to the right of the path and exactly vertical between the Agent and Environment node?
2. How can I move the path to the left just slightly out the node and then up before turning right to the agent node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! I think your code can benefit from a row of small enhancements.

First, you don't need to add multiple `\tikzset` macros inside the `tikzpicture` environment. Instead, just put the defintions into the optional argument of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Second, Ti*k*Z already defines a `double` style that you might want to use here (you would need to call your style differently in order not to override this predefined style, of course). A thicker arrow tip would fit better in my opinion.

Third, I think, the positioning of the coordinates that define the arrow could be simplified and also unified as suggested in the code below. I added the option `text depth` to the text nodes to make their height equal.

Finally, to place the `$A_t$` node exactly to the right and vertically align it between the two other nodes, you should know the following: When you use tha `|-` (or `-|`) markup, you can use `pos=0.5` to denote the coordinate where the path changes its direction from vertical to horizontal (or vice versa). Further, `pos=0.25` (and `pos=0.75`) denote the center of the vertical (or horizontal) part of the path from its start to this coordinate. Therefore, it is very easy to place the `$A_t$` node where you want it to be places using this approach.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth[length=7pt]},
    rect/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text depth=0.1em
    },
    single arrow/.style={
        ->
    },
    double arrow/.style={
        double,
        double distance=1pt,
        ->
    }]
    % Nodes
    \node[rect] (agent) at (0,0) {Agent};
    \node[below=of agent, rect] (environment) {Environment};
    
    \draw[single arrow] (agent) -- ++(1.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25, right] {$A_t$} (environment);
    
    \draw[double arrow] (environment) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- (agent);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you provided an image of the intended result, I add this edited suggestion. A `double` arrow is drawn very differently from two arrows. Also, with your approach, you won't be able to simply attach two arrow tips to both lines and it is also complicated to draw the path around two corners. Therefore, I would suggest that you simply draw two arrows and shift the coordinates of the arrow paths accordingly (the following code is probably not the easiest way to achieve this, but it shows different ways how to shift and align coordinates that may be of some help for you):

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    rect/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text depth=0.1em
    }]
    % Nodes
    \node[rect] (agent) at (0,0) {Agent};
    \node[below=of agent, rect] (environment) {Environment};
    
    \draw[->, thick] (agent) -- ++(2.5,0) |- 
        node[pos=0.25, right] {$A_t$} (environment);
    
    \coordinate (lower west) at ([shift={(-2cm, -2pt)}]environment.center);
    \coordinate (upper west) at ([shift={(-2cm, 2pt)}]environment.center);
    
    \draw[densely dotted] ([yshift=5pt]upper west) -- ([yshift=-5pt]lower west);
    
    \draw[->] (environment.west |- upper west) -- (upper west)
        node[midway, above] {$R_{t+1}$};
        
    \draw[->, thick] (environment.west |- lower west) -- (lower west)
        node[midway, below] {$S_{t+1}$};

    \draw[->] (upper west) -- ++({-0.5cm + 2pt},0) |- 
        node[pos=0.25, right] {$R_t$} ([yshift=-2pt]agent.west);
        
    \draw[->, thick] (lower west) -- ++({-0.5cm - 2pt},0) |- 
        node[pos=0.25, left] {$S_t$} ([yshift=2pt]agent.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That helps a lot! Although, the left arrow needs to look a bit different, more like two separate arrows (which is what I was looking for). See the original from Sutton's book on reinforcement learning: https://imgur.com/a/CgVgmWT
I'm interested how the arrow was done, the parts right of the dotted line I can figure out myself (hopefully).

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot Well, if it should be actually two arrows, you should just place two arrows. The two arrows in the picture are of different thickness, so it really makes sense to just draw two arrows, I think. See my edit.

Comment: +1 for the great tutorial, errr, answer.